# UIViewAlert leads to "unrecognized selector passed to instance" - already checked previous posts

Tags: ios

Wishing everybody a Happy and Prosperous 2014!

I spent the last 3 days fighting an issue with UIViewAlert leading to error “unrecognized selector passed to instance” and am hoping somebody can provide clues!

My hierarchy of ViewControllers is:

AppDelegate loads ViewController VC1 by setting VC1 to be its rootVC using code like this:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:newNavController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

VC1 pushes DropboxVC (view controller)

DropboxVC tries to raise UIViewAlert e.g. when a user tries to unlink from Dropbox and is already unlinked, or when a sync operation completes. The UIViewAlert ends with error

> [DocsAppDelegate _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d24be0

The instance 0x14d23be0 is clearly my AppDelegate instance which I presume, has not been freed?

I trolled through previous threads and ensured that my UIViewAlert OtherButtonTitles is nil terminated. I also tried both – directly raising the UIViewAlert in DropboxVC and also doing it in main thread via

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlertWithTitle:)
                           withObject:@"Application is already linked to Dropbox"
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And the alert itself is

```
- (void)showAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)DispMsg
{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                    message:DispMsg
                                  delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
```

Since it's not working, and I am setting VC1 to be RootVC in AppDelegate, I made sure that both my AppDelegate AND VC1 define the `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` and `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` defined. I have logging in all these methods and none are triggering. I also set breakpoints and none are triggering.

My .plist declares the app to support all 4 orientations. I am not using Storyboards. My `mainwindow.xib` is set to full screen.

Any clues as to what I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I have enough to go on, but the error message is clear. The app delegate is being passed the message `-_viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientations` which is a private message for view controllers. Somewhere the app delegate is being assign to something which expects a view controller.

Comment: This often happens with memory leaks. Make sure you properly retain what you should retain (or if you are using ARC that you are using the proper type of reference, e.g strong/weak)

Comment: Can you please post some code of how you initialize the controllers and when you display the alert view? ... Also is the crash occurs when the alert view is just displayed or after you press on "ok" button?

Comment: Thx for quick responses! In my AppDelegate, here is how I "launch" the ViewController VC1 as referred to in my postRootViewController *newController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
[newController setWindow:window];
newNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newController]
[window addSubview:[newNavController view]];
[self.window setRootViewController:newNavController];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
I agree that AppDelegate is being assigned a VC. What do I need to do to have that AND allow an UIAlertView to work?

Comment: in RootViewController which I referred to as VC1, I did make sure that RootVC is UIViewAlertDelegate and I also defined the interface orientation as well UIViewAlert ClickedButtonAtIndex methods. The crash happens before the UIViewAlert is displayed

Comment: I finally gave up. I started a new project, verified that UIViewAlert works and then moved over my code one ViewController at a time, and it works now!

Comment: I've encountered the exact problem as you have. A _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientations is sent to one of my singleton(not AppDelegate) and I have no idea how it happened, I suspect it is an iOS7 bug, what do you say?